# Powershell How to store a function output in a string?

Tags: string, powershell, powershell-2.0, store

I just wrote a small script which displays the latest event-logs of my choice.

Now I want to store the output in a string, but I didn't manage to do that.

Here is my function  :

```
function geteventlog
{

get-eventlog -logname System -EntryType Error -newest 2 |  Select-Object message,source | fl *

}
```

Powershell 2.0

Comment: Storing the output as a string is doing it wrong. Store it a a collection of objects by doing this: $out = GetEventLog

Comment: ok thanks for help, thats what i tried already but there is another script which uses my output later on and somehow he cant handle that.

Comment: Note: The `fl *` will completely hork any variable storing. It will end up storing formats instead of a custom object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storing function output is simple:

```
$result = geteventlog
```

Converting the output to a string is also pretty simple and can be done like so:

```
$result = geteventlog | Out-String
```

Note that Out-String has a `Width` parameter that allows to control how wide the resulting output is.